# Audio play and stop on button click

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have been trying to make a button to play and stop an audio when clicked but can't get it to work. Need some help please

```
let audio, playBtn;
playBtn = document.querySelector("#playPauseBtn");

const playPause = () => {
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.paused = true;
  audio.src = "music/amor.mp3";
  if (audio.paused === true) {
    audio.play();
    audio.paused = false;
    playBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";

  } else if (audio.paused === false) {
    audio.pause();
    playBtn.innerHTML = "Play";

  }
}
playBtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
```

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting

Comment: You are declaring a new Audio object each time the button is pressed, move it out of the callback function ```playPause```.

Answer (score 1):

As @christopher_pk pointed out, you are creating a new audio object everytime which will reset the audio to the beginning everytime you press the button.
Instead, declare the audio outside:

```js
let audio, playBtn;
playBtn = document.querySelector("#playPauseBtn");

audio = new Audio();
audio.paused = true;
audio.src = "https://www.random.org/audio-noise/?channels=2&volume=100&rate=16000&size=8&date=2018-07-06&format=wav&deliver=browser";

const playPause = () => {
    if (audio.paused === true) {
        audio.play();
        audio.paused = false;
        playBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
    } else if (audio.paused === false) {
        audio.pause();
        playBtn.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
}
playBtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
```

```html
<button id="playPauseBtn">Play</button>
```